# Runtime Error! - Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Tags: visual-c++

I've developed an application in VS 2003 (C++). But while running in a fresh windows xp machine, getting error:

### Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library

Runtime Error!

Program:

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way....

What will be the reason for getting this error and how can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: Try looking at the system error log / event viewer - it may contain more detail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427

Answer (score 2):

This is a very generic error so it is not easy to solve from this information but I can give you a few things to try.

First check that the program runs fine on your developer machine - if not run under the debugger and trap the specific error.

If this problem only occurs on the clean machine it probably does not have the correct runtimes installed.

Your application will depend on a number of dlls that ship with visual studio, you will need to install these on the clean machine.

Your can run depends.exe from http://www.dependencywalker.com/ this will tell you what dlls cannot be found.

These dlls will be on your developer machine, you can either package the yourself in an installer or find the correct redistributable from microsoft.

Another thing to check - have you hardcoded any file locations? e.g. your application could try and open a file, resource, registry key - something that does not exist in your clean machine - if the code does not check for failure you would then probably crash at some point after the read failed to happen.